# Jira email notifications not working, but test e-mail is working

Tags: email, jira

We have an on-premise hosted Jira 6.0.8. We have set up an outgoing mail server using a Gmail account and used the send test e-mail feature to successfully send an e-mail out.

Our problem is with e-mail notifications. We are not getting any at all. We have gone through troubleshooting docs https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/troubleshoot-notifications-in-jira-203394737.html here but have not been able to find the solution.

Here is what we have already tried;

1. Ensured user profile **'My Changes setting'** was set to **'Notify Me'**
2. Ensured Notification scheme was correct and associated with the project
3. Ensured Project Notification email was set to the same as the outgoing mail server Gmail address
4. Checked the **'Mail Queue'** after making a comment on an issue and saw waiting messages in it for the correct issue. These then disappeared from the queue without error within 60 seconds, indicating that they had been sent.
5. Enabled DEBUG logging under **'Logging and Profiling'** for the outgoing mail server and *com.atlassian.jira.service* and *com.atlassian.jira.service.services.DebugService*. We reviewed the log file and saw nothing that indicated error but did see the log of the MailqueueService sending the e-mail.
6. have used the **'Notifcation Helper'** tool and it verified that the user would receive the appropriate notification indicating notifcation scheme and permission are set up ok.

Still the notification e-mail is not received.

There was a point made in the troubleshooting [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/troubleshoot-notifications-in-jira-203394737.html) above

> Check that your Base URL is set to a domain / IP which your SMTP server will accept. Example: Google apps accounts must have a matching base url to their Google Apps domain.

However, our **Adminsistration> System>General Configuration>Base Url** for Jira is something like *http://myservername:8880* since it is internal self-hosted. This did not cause a problem with the test mail. Could this be an issue for the notification e-mails?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the emails are being received by the mail server or not? For example, you could spin up a local container running Mailcatcher and point Jira at it for outgoing SMTP. This will allow you to see all of the received emails, which will help rule out any filtering at the mail sever (and also allow you to verify the logs, if necessary).

Comment: @ScottDudley Sorry for the long delay in replying and many thanks for your great suggestion. I'd never heard of mailcatcher. I set it up and was able to set outgoing mail from Jira to it, and all mail was received in mailcatcher ok. It must be the gmail sever rejecting it.